# How many weeks?

Tags: code-golf, date

**Your task** is to output a single number; the number of ISO weeks that a given date range intersects. To quote Wikipedia: `An average year is exactly 52.1775 weeks long`, but this is not about the average.

**Input** consists of two space-separated ISO dates:

```
0047-12-24 2013-06-01
```

The end date is never before the start date. We'll use the extrapolated Gregorian calendar for simplicity.

**Test cases:**

```
Format: input -> output
2015-12-31 2016-01-01 -> 1    (both are within week 53 of 2015)
2016-01-03 2016-01-04 -> 2    (the 3rd is within week 53, and the 4th is in week 1)
2015-12-24 2015-12-24 -> 1    (this single day is of course within a single week)
```

Your solution should handle dates between `0001-01-01` and `9999-12-31`.

Comment: Can the input be an array of strings instead of a single space-separated string? Alternatively, can the two dates be two arguments to a function?

Comment: I assume you mean [Proleptic Gregorian Calendar](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Proleptic+Gregorian+Calendar&ia=about).

Comment: Also, do weeks start on Sunday or Monday? According to your second test case, it's Monday, but just making sure.

Comment: @Doorknob冰  Wikipedia quote: "A date is specified by the ISO week-numbering year in the format YYYY, a week number in the format ww prefixed by the letter 'W', and the weekday number, a digit d from 1 through 7, beginning with Monday and ending with Sunday" So starting on Monday as per ISO 8601

Comment: According to the ISO standard, `Weeks start with Monday.`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills yes. I used the term that wolframalpha uses, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>89</s> <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```ruby
->s{a,b=s.split.map{|x|Time.gm *x.split(?-)}
n=1
(a+=86400).wday==1&&n+=1until a==b
n}
```

A very primitive solution: given the first date `a` and the second date `b`, increment `a`, check if it's a Monday (if so, we've "rolled over" to a new week), and stop once `a` is `b`.

Takes input in the exact format specified in the question: a single space-separated string. (The way it parses the input is fancy-ish: it uses Ruby's "splat" operator, `*`. This operator "expands" an array or enumerable out, so `Time.gm *[2013, 06, 01]` becomes `Time.gm 2013, 06, 01`.)

Imported from a comment discussion:

> We don't care about "weeks in a year;" we only care about "weeks overall." So whether a year has 52 or 53 weeks doesn't make any difference.

Just to avoid future confusion with whether this handles year boundaries correctly—[according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), all weeks always start on Monday and end on Sunday.

For some more fancy tricks, these are all equivalent:

```ruby
until a==b;a+=86400;n+=a.wday==1?1:0;end
[a+=86400,n+=a.wday==1?1:0]until a==b
n+=(a+=86400).wday==1?1:0 until a==b
(a+=86400).wday==1&&n+=1 until a==b
(a+=86400).wday==1&&n+=1until a==b
```

Comment: Can't you can save 1 char replacing `a==b` by `a<b` ?

Answer (score 1):

## VBA , 125 Bytes

Expecting 2 function inputs as strings

```
Function u(k,j)
f=DateValue(k)
For i=0 To (DateValue(j)-f)
q=DatePart("ww",f+i,2,2)
If q<>j Then u=u+1
j=q
Next
End Function
```

Pretty sure This can be golfed. This is looping though everyday between the 2 dates and increments the counter every time the ISO date changes.

`DatePart("ww",f+i,2,2)` is the ISO week number in VBA the first 2 means `Monday (complies with ISO standard 8601, section 3.17)`. then second 2 means `Week that has at least four days in the new year (complies with ISO standard 8601, section 3.17)`

#### 140 bytes w/single input

```
Function g(k)
y=Split(k)
f=DateValue(y(0))
For i=0 To (DateValue(y(1))-f)
q=DatePart("ww",f+i,2,2)
If q<>j Then g=g+1
j=q
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 76 bytes

```
d=as.Date(scan("","raw"));sum(strftime(seq(d[1],d[2],"day")[-1],"%w")==1)+1
```

After the talk with @Doorknob, it's finally as easy as counting the Mondays.

`seq` allow to create a vector of dates (of each day between two dates) and strftime transform it to the 'number of the day in the week', now counts the times it's 1 to get the number of time you changed week and add 1 to take in account previous week.

Another approach looping:

### R, 85 bytes

```
n=1;d=as.Date(scan("","raw"));z=d[1];while(z<d[2]){n=n+(strftime(z<-z+1,"%w")==1)};n
```

Comment: Regarding your second approach, you should only add 1 to the total number of Mondays if the first date does not fall on a Monday.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thanks, reading your answer made me think I could remove the first day of range, thus fixing the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica <s>135 79 96 84</s> 74 bytes

Consistent with @Doorknob's suggestion, this

- generates all the dates in the range
- counts the number of Mondays (`ISOWeekDay` =="1") in the `DateRange`(excluding `d`), and
- adds `1` to the total.

---

```
Count[DateString[#,"ISOWeekDay"]&/@Rest@(DateRange@@StringSplit@#),"1"]+1&
```

---

```
Count[DateString[#,"ISOWeekDay"]&/@Rest@(DateRange@@StringSplit@#),"1"]+1&
/@ {"2015-12-31 2016-01-01", "2016-01-04 2016-01-05","2016-01-03 2016-01-04", 
"2015-12-24 2015-12-24", "1876-12-24 2016-01-01"}
```

> {1, 1, 2, 1, 7255}